# jqgrid date column filter with datepicker

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with a Date column. I like to implement a filter option for the column with a datepicker on the column filter textbox.

I have already formatted the column to display the date values in specific format of d-M-y, using the formatoptions attribute.

I implemented the same using the datainit event with a datepicker for the column. But, filter is not working on selection of date using the datepicker.
I doubt, the format differences between the column value display and the datepicker of the column filter as the reason behind this.

Even though, after making both the formats same, filter does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Manikandan J

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get datepicker in jqGrid search toolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408115/how-to-get-datepicker-in-jqgrid-search-toolbar)

Comment: I'm not sure that I correctly understand your problem. You should include **more details** about what you do and in what format have you input data. Minimal information is: which fork of jqGrid and in which version you use, which format have **input data** (for example `2015-07-21T14:24:00`), how you define the column in `colModel` with the datepicker, if you use `filterToolbar` then it's important to know the options which you use.

Comment: I am wondering how to do this as well. So I have a date column and a filter. When I put the cursor on the filter field, I want to date picker to appear so I can put a date in to filter the column. Can this be done?